# Data Type Mismatch error in Criteria Expression

Tags: c#

```
cmdLocl.CommandText = "Patientdtls_spi";
cmdLocl.Connection = cnLocl;
cmdLocl.Transaction = trnLocl;
cmdLocl.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPname", drTmp["Patient_Name"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strAge", drTmp["Patient_Age"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intSex", drTmp["Patient_Sex"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strDoctor", drTmp["Patient_RfdDr"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strLabId", drTmp["LabId"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blnSmprcvd",Convert.ToBoolean(drTmp["Sample_Rcvd"]));
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtSmpdlvd", drTmp["Sample_Dlvd"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dblAmtopay", drTmp["AmtToPay"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dblAmtpaid", drTmp["AmtPaid"]);
cmdLocl.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dblAmtpndg", drTmp["AmtPending"]);
cmdLocl.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I am running this code I am getting error like Data Type Mismatch Error I criteria expression at `cmdLocl.ExecuteNonquey()`. I am using MS Access database, The data type of Sample_Rcvd is Yes/No in database.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the stored procedure seems the sp parameter type you passed didnot match with the one you defined.Use a breadkpoint to check the values of the parameters passed

Comment: drTmp is temperory Datarow and this is my stored procedure INSERT INTO Patientdetails ( Patient_Name, Patient_Age, Patient_Sex, Patient_RfdDr, LabId, Sample_Rcvd, Sample_Dlvd, AmtToPay, AmtPaid, AmtPending )
SELECT [@strPname], [@strAge], [@intSex], [@strDoctor], [@strLabId], [@blnSmprcvd], [@dtSmpdlvd], [@dblAmtopay], [@dblAmtpaid], [@dblAmtpndg];
When I checked through break point data is filling in the datatable structure